# How do you find the number of contestants in a tv show based on their eye colors?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, recreational-mathematics

The problem is as follows:

> To participate in an edition of *The Price is Right* $60$ people
> showed up. The producer of the show collected the following
> information:
>
> $10$ women have black eyes $16$ women don't have black eyes $14$ women
> do not have brown eyes $10$ men do not have brown or black eyes
>
> Based on information from the show's producer. How many men have brown
> or black eyes?

The alternatives in my book are as follows:

$\begin{array}{ll}
1.&\textrm{24 men}\\
2.&\textrm{22 men}\\
3.&\textrm{18 men}\\
4.&\textrm{28 men}\\
5.&\textrm{20 men}\\
\end{array}$

What I attempted to do is summarized in the table from below which showcases my findings. I must indicate that I arranged the characters of the story in two groups. One for women and the other for men. One column indicates $F$ for false of those who do not have a certain characteristic, i.e. A man who does not have black eyes would be in the F column below black eyes, a woman who has black eyes will lie below T in the black eyes column.

Hence this is represented as:

[image: Sketch of the table]

Where $x+y=10$

Adding all of these yields:

$14+10+16 +x+y+a+b=60$

Since it mentions $x+y=10$ and they want to know what is a+b then this would mean:

$a+b=60-50=10$

However this is not within the alternatives.

In my effort to better represent this situation and avoid counting twice I made the diagram from below:

[image: Sketch of the problem]

This different representation using an Euler diagram shows what I thought, the set of those who do not have brown eyes must account for those who have black eyes.

There is no interesection in any of these sets as there cannot be someone who has brown and black eyes at the same time. Thus I concluded what they want is the number of men who have brown eyes and those who have black eyes.

**This part I require clarification, what is the meaning of OR translated in set theory language?.** Does it mean is it a Union?. Is it $\cup$?. Can someone help me with this part?.

Returning to my attempt I then thought that the number $14$ of those who do not have brown eyes will include those who have black eyes therefore.

Adding those who have black eyes with those who have brown eyes with those who dont have brown neither black in the women side. With those on the men side who dont have neither black or brown with those who have brown and those who have black will equate to $60$. This translated into an equation would be as this:

14+16+10+u=60

Assuming $u=\textrm{unknown males with brown with those with black eyes}$

This would become into:

$u=20\,men$

But this is not the right answer. **Why**?.

Did I made a mistake or something?. Because of this reason I need a **very detailed help with this**.

**Please an answer must include a Venn or Euler diagram strategy** or using a table. To better aid the understanding of this problem. I have tried all sorts, but I don't seem to get the right answer.

Can someone **include also the representation of set notation using algebraic notation** accompanied with an Euler or Table diagram?.

Comment: Idk how to make a diagram, but "60 contestants": "10 women have black eyes 16 women don't have black eyes"<-- that alone should tell you there are 26 women since either women have black eyes or they don't, that part is that simple. That should tell you there are $60-26=34$ men since the contestants are either men or women. Next, "10 men do not have brown or black eyes" is the only info that could relate to men's eye colors--and it tells us that there are $34-10=24$ men with brown or black eyes, for similar reasoning I used before: they either have brown or black eyes or they don't.

Comment: In addition, as player3236 notes, you can't add all your data and set it equal to 60 since some of the data can hold true more than once. For example, there are 3 people, 2 are wearing glasses and have a red shirt, while 2 are wearing a hat, one has a red shirt, the other has a blue shirt... you can't always add 'em up.

Comment: @CottonHeadedNinnymuggins Howdy! Sorry for the late reply. This question was under the topic of sets in my book, and from looking at it, *the intended approach was to rely on Venn-Euler diagrams* hence my requirement to use those to explain and solve this problem. Yes I've got you when you mention that when it says *one group has black eyes* whatever the rest is the complement, but upon initial reading **I felt dumbfounded on why did it mentioned other colors this part confused me the most**. Those diagrams I used Inkscape, i think they can be done use MS Word or MS Powerpoint?. Mind trying?

Answer (score 2):

You are given:

> 10 women have black eyes
>
> 16 women don't have black eyes
>
> 14 women do not have brown eyes
>
> 10 men do not have brown or black eyes

Assuming no one have heterochromia, each person only has one single eye color.

Hence either they *have* black eyes, or they *do not*.

From the first two conditions we see that there are $26$ women. Thus there are $34$ men.

Now $10$ men *do not have* brown or black eyes, and we are to find the number of men *with* brown or black eyes, which is the complement of those $10$ men, so there are $24$ of them.

The major mistake in your answer is the equation

$$14+10+16+x+y+a+b=60$$

Since the $14$ women without brown eyes and those $16$ women without black eyes are not mutually exclusive, you can't just add them up; you will overcount.

To answer your side question, OR translates to the union $\cup$ and AND translates to the intersection $\cap$. However these do not come into play in this specific question.

Comment: Howdy! Sorry for the late reply. Yes the part of the operator AND and its representation as $\cap$ and OR as $\cup$ was making me feel confused. Assuming those would come into play, which sort of statement would had hinted those?. Because when I read, the part *10 men don't have brown or black eyes* made me think that was necessary. Sorry but for me it was not very obvious that the number of women were $26$ I mean the clue regarding *14 women have brown eyes* where would this be **included**?. Should it be in the set for those who don't have brown eyes?.

Comment: Because of such reason I did mentioned to you that I required a *Venn-Euler diagram* to spot where these are as means of better visual representation. Since I got this question in my book under set theory it could help me the most if you included a diagram. Or telling me what part of my representation was not right?.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. There are 60 contestants

> 2. 10 women *have* black eyes 16 women *don't* have black eyes

> 3. 10 men do not have brown or black eyes

I will try to give as best an explanation as I can possibly give:

Notice, statement 2 will represent all women, since they have black eyes or don't. Just like if I were to say there are 2 guys with a shirt and 3 without: there are 5 guys. So back to statement 2, $10+16=26$ so there are $\boxed{26 women}$

Since there are 26 women, this means $60-26=34$ so there are $\boxed{34 men}$ since the contestants are women ***or they aren't*** just like above, the women either have black eyes ***or they don't***

Statement 3 suggests there are 10 men ****without*** brown or black eyes*, the opposite of that would be men ****with*** brown or black eyes*. And as I've done through the whole answer, we have $34-10=24$ $\boxed{24}$ *men ***with*** brown or black eyes*

The logic of this whole answer is basically: There are $n$ number of things with the attribute(s) $X$ and $s$ number of things without attribute(s) $X$, so there are $n+s$ number of things total.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. Yes I understood your explanation regarding exclusion. At first it was not very obvious for me that there were $26$ women. Because of this reason I requested a solution using a visual representation using a $\textrm{Venn-Euler diagram}$ since I found this question in my book under the chapter of set theory. The clue regarding the men which don't have brown and black eyes color made me confused as I didn't know how to represent this correctly. If you wouldn't mind can you help me with a clarification using a diagram for this?.

Comment: By the way, I had a similar confusion understanding [this set problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3882653/how-to-find-the-number-of-a-students-using-sets-when-different-clauses-are-state) perhaps could you help me with this as well?. If you look closely those seem to be related but the other seems to have higher difficulty and I got confused into trying to use a Venn-Euler diagram for that.